# How to set up Google Authorship relationship between post page, post list page and author page?

Tags: seo, google-plus, canonical-link, author

I have a review website with multiple authors. Authors review spots. Several authors can review one spot. The key is for the spot page to be considered the most important page while still using Google Authorship.

Site structure:

- www.site.com/spot-name (Spot page)
- www.site.com/authors/author-name (Author page)
- www.site.com/reviews/review-title (Review page)
- Spot page = Short intro to spot + list of all full text reviews for that spot
- Author page = Short intro to author + list of links to all reviews by author
- Review page = Contains a single review

The problem:

It seems like you should not have several author tags on one page, so I need the review page to exist to contain the link with the author tag which goes to the author page. But as the content on the review page is a duplicate of a part of the content on the spot page, I am afraid of trouble with Google. If I use a canonical tag to point out that the spot page is most important while at the same time linking from both the author page and spot page to the review page, it seems like Google might get confused about this.

Possible solutions:

1. Remove the review page. List reviews on spot page with each review separated with the  tag and link to author page from bylines within each review. Thus having several rel=author links on one page, but clearly separated from each other.
2. Use a canonical tag from review page to spot page.
3. Use title of review on spot page as no-follow link to review page, then use a normal do-follow link from review page to spot page.
4. ??

What would you do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use metatags from "The Open Graph protocol":
http://ogp.me/
For example tag "article:author" from  namespace URI: http://ogp.me/ns/article#
Also meet with the information Google:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1408986?hl=en
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1708844?hl=en
I hope that this will help you

Comment: I don't believe any of these links answered my question which was about how to handle multiple pieces of content from multiple authors on the very same page.